# How to use pass TypeGraphQL resolver into buildSubgraphSchema when federating a GraphQL service

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, typegraphql

I am trying to federate a service but having no luck passing through the schema and resolvers to the `buildSubgraphSchema` method in the `Apollo` constructor. Is this even possible?